# sinon: when stubs restored?

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, sinon

I am using sinon 1.17.6. Below is my codes:

```
  it('should', sinon.test(function(/*done*/) {
      const stubtoBeStubbedFunction = this.stub(this.myObj, 'toBeStubbedFunction');
      const instance = {
        id: 'instanceId',
        tCount: 3,
      };
      console.log('0 toBeStubbedFunction', this.myObj.toBeStubbedFunction);
      return this.myObj.toBeTestedFunction(instance)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('3 toBeStubbedFunction', this.myObj.toBeStubbedFunction);
          expect(stubtoBeStubbedFunction.calledOnce).to.be.true();
          // done();
        });
  }));


MyClass.prototype.toBeTestedFunction = function toBeTestedFunction(input) {
  const metaData = {};
  this.log.debug('toBeTestedFunction');
  if (input.tCount === 0) {
    console.log('1', this.toBeStubbedFunction);
    return bluebird.resolve((this.toBeStubbedFunction(metaData)));
  }

  return this.myClient.getData(input.id)
    .bind(this)
    .then(function _on(res) {
      if (res) {
        console.log('2', this.toBeStubbedFunction);
        this.toBeStubbedFunction(metaData);
      }
    })
    .catch(function _onError(err) {
      throw new VError(err, 'toBeTestedFunctionError');
    });
};
```

console.log output:

```
0 toBeStubbedFunction toBeStubbedFunction
2 function toBeStubbedFunction(meta) {
  // real implementation
}
3 toBeStubbedFunction function toBeStubbedFunction(meta) {
  // real implementation
}
```

It seems that during test running, the stubbed function is restored. I thought `sinon.test()` should restore stubs after returned promise resolved or caught (stubs should be restored after `console.log('2', this.toBeStubbedFunction);` run). **Why?** I used `done` to solve my issue. But are there better solutions? I may use `mocha` and `sinon` the wrong way.

Any comments welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sinon.test` method provided by Sinon 1.x completely ignores promises returned by tests, which means it does not wait for the promise to resolve before resetting the sandbox it creates.

[Sinon 2.x](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.0.0/migrating-to-2.0/) removed `sinon.test` from Sinon and spun it as its own separate [`sinon-test` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-test). It initially had the same problem as the `sinon.test` method provided by Sinon 1.x but the problem was [reported and resolved](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon-test/issues/6).

The peer dependencies of `sinon-test` are currently setting a minimum version for Sinon of 2.x so at a minimum you'd have to upgrade Sinon and add `sinon-test` to your test suite to have support for promises and use the test wrapper provided `sinon-test`.

Or you could abandon the wrapper and write your own `before/beforeEach` and `after/afterEach` hooks that would take care of creating and resetting a sandbox for you. I've used Sinon for years (certainly from the 1.x series onwards, possibly even earlier) and that's always what I've done. I did not even know about `sinon.test` until I saw the other question you asked about it a few days ago.